# How we can Dump kafka topic into presto

Tags: apache-kafka, presto, kafka-producer-api, connector

I need to  pushing a JSON file into a Kafka topic, connecting the topic in presto and structuring the JSON data into a queryable table.

I am following this tutorial https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html#step-2-load-data

I am not able to understand how this command will work.

$ ./kafka-tpch load --brokers localhost:9092 --prefix tpch. --tpch-type tiny

Suppose I have created test topic in kafka using producer. How will tpch file will generate of this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a topic, you should skip to step 3 where it actually sets up the topics to query via Presto

`kafka-tpch load` creates new topics with the specified prefix

Comment: We need to create description file in etc/kafka which should map the colums. But I am not getting the table which has column which i mentioned in description file.

Comment: Your topic is listed in catalog/kafka.properties as a table and you restarted Presto after adding it?

Comment: You should verify that the topic appears as a table before adding a schema file

Answer (score 0):

Above command creates a tpch schema and loads various tables under it. This can be used for testing purpose. If you want to work with your actual kafka topics, you need to enlist them in /catalog/kafka.properties against kafka.tables-names. If you simply provide a topic name without prefix (such as test_topic), it would land into "default" schema. However, if you specify a topic name with prefix (such as test_schema.test_topic), then the topic would appear under test_schema. While querying using presto, you can provide this schema name.